# Restoring CRM Organizations after Dynamics 365 upgrade

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics, unified-service-desk

We recently upgraded to Dynamics 365 from CRM Online 2016. As a result all our CRM Organizations and Regions are no longer appearing in the Unified Service Desk CRM Organization selection window. Kindly advise on how to restore.

Comment: Are you using the latest USD ?

Comment: I am not sure? do I need to upgrade the latest USD as well? Please provide info if i need to upgrade USD as well.

Comment: I have no hands-on experience on USD, but if it's anything like the Outlook client, it should always be upgraded to match the CRM version.

Answer (score 0):

It Seems that you were force updated, acoording to the [Update Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/admin/manage-updates#update-policy) the minor version supported is n-2 (8.1 in the current scenario) if you want to go back to 8.0 it won't be possible cause isn't supported any more, if you want to go back to any of the supported previous versions could [restore one of the snapshot of the database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/admin/backup-restore-instances) that if aven't pass more than 3 days, in that case you could create a customer support ticket and ask for an older backup

Hope it helps